# How to access docker container running in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: docker, cassandra, google-cloud-platform

I just started yesterday and following tutorials for using GCP.

I have a Cassandra docker container running in google compute engine. I would like to connect to the Cassandra docker container from my local machine and load data into it.

I tried using the IP address of the compute instance and Cassandra port. But the java program which loads data into Cassandra throws an error NoHostAvailableException

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Try adding `--network=host` to your docker run command. Cassandra reports its own IP address to the cluster so any more than 1 node and you'll start having problems using docker IP.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, unless you expose the docker container's port publicly, you cannot access the port of the container anyway. This is where the concept of services comes in cloud architectures, to publicly expose container/s. Detailed instruction is given in "configuring endpoints" and following sections in the following article https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine-docker .